# How to export the IIS site deatils to excel sheet from multiple servers using Poweshell script

Tags: powershell

I had written a script where the script will give only the one server IIS details, but I need the IIS site details from multiple servers using the same script.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration


    get-website | select Name,Id,State,physicalpath,
    @{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ‘;’ }} ,
    @{n="LogFile";e={ $_.logfile | select -expa directory}},
    @{n="attributes"; e={($_.attributes | % { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ‘;’ }}| 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Temp\IIS_sites.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We do not write ready to use code on request. We expect you to spend an effort to solve your problem yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**Note that this wont work if winRM is closed on your remote machines**

```bsh
$Machines = @('machine1','machine2') # list of your machines
foreach($M in $Machines)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $M -ScriptBlock {
    & { 
        # your script here
    }
}

}
```

Also , if you expect to an output from your commands, and want to save them in different variables, use this one :

```bsh
$Responses = Invoke-Command -ComputerName somecomp -ScriptBlock { (Get-Website), (Get-Process) }

#IIS Sites:
$Responses[0]

#Processes
$Responses[1]
```

Comment: I have used the above logic to write the code
```$Machines = @('IN-LINGARCR-1','USTR-ERL2-2696') # list of your machines
foreach($M in $Machines)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $M -ScriptBlock {
    & {
   Get-Website | Select-Object Name,Id,State,PhysicalPath,
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ‘;’ }} ,
@{n="attributes"; e={($_.attributes | % { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ‘;’ }} 
}
}

} 
 Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Temp\IIS_sites.csv


```

Comment: but when i run the script in the output windows i am getting all the site details, but when it is trying export the destails to Excel sheet, it asking the input object value as below:

cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

when i provide any value in Input Object: in the excel sheet it will give just the length of the value